# Calling a specific method onClickListener

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have a java class that adds data to my sqlite db as follows:

```
public class DataProvider {
    public static List<DataItem> dataItemList;
    public static Map<String, DataItem> dataItemMap;

    static {
        dataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
        dataItemMap = new HashMap<>();

        addItem(new DataItem(null, "Row 1", "Description 1", 3107));
        addItem(new DataItem(null, "Row 2", "Description 2", 2519));
    }

    public static void addItem(DataItem item) {
        dataItemList.add(item);
        dataItemMap.put(item.getAccountId(), item);
    }

}
```

Where `DataItem` is a model class that handles data information.

I then created a new activity with a button that would utilize `addItem` from this class:

```
    Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addItem(new DataItem(null, "Row 3", "Description 3", 3307));
            finish();
        }
    });
```

**Attempt**

1. I tried by statically importing `addItem` from my `DataProvider`
   class but it did not work.
2. I created a new method within the activity with the button to be used for the `addItem`, still no luck.

   ```
   private void addItem(DataItem item) {
       List<DataItem> dataItemList;
       Map<String, DataItem> dataItemMap;
       dataItemList = new ArrayList<>();
       dataItemMap = new HashMap<>();
       dataItemList.add(item);
       dataItemMap.put(item.getAccountId(), item);
   }
   ```

**Question**

How else am I able to import `addItem` to be able to use it within `onClick` method inside my second activity?

Answer (score 2):

As I see Your data structure is static so it can be used everywhere after importing it. It is no need to create any methods in controller, data provider can be used directly everywhere so also in listener :

```
DataProvider.addItem (/* new item */ )
```

Comment: That is the strange thing however, doing `DataProvider.addItem` is not appending any data to the DB.

Comment: As I see there is only adding element to list and map. Where is db code?

Comment: It is in the `DataItem` class which is quite lengthy to add here. As you see, calling `addItem` from within the `DataProvider` class has successfully appended the rows to the db.

Comment: But that means creating new instance od Data item is doing db insert. So what sense has data provider if it is doing only adding to list? Something is wrong here.

Comment: `DataProvider` was used to hard code data entry to the DB and to allow data entry in the format shown above. `DataItem` has the actual `.put` method that goes into the table. So are you saing utilizing `DataProvider` is incorrect?

Comment: Thank you for the help +1, I was able to pinpoint the problem and fixed it. It was in another java class, I misunderstood the structure at first and how `DataProvider` and `DataItem` were interacting.

Answer (score 1):

You should try like creating separate method and calling that method in your OnClickListener

```
private void addItem(DataItem item) {
    DataProvider.addItem(item)
}
```

Or
Directly call that  method from your OnClickListener like,

```
DataProvider.addItem(new DataItem(null, "Row 3", "Description 3", 3307));
```

And also check your import for addItem method

Comment: I tried both of those and neither are appending data to the database. I have both `DataProvider` and `DataItem` imported in the current activity. I previously also had `DataProvider.addItem` imported when I was calling `addItem` on its own.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why can't you use a java class' static method in a different activity.

**My Suggestions-**

1)Make Dataprovider class abstract and then let the main class of second activity extend it. Then just override the method there in second activity.

2) Make an instance of the Dataprovider class in the first activity then let your Dataprovider class implement Serializable interface. Then you can send your object along with whatever intent thats calling your second activity. Try this-

```
    // send where details is object
ClassName details = new ClassName();
Intent i = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Editing", details);
startActivity(i);


//receive
ClassName model = (ClassName) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Editing");

And 

Class ClassName implements Serializable {
}
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

just called static method of dataprovider and it worked like below

```
/**
 * method which is called on click 
 * i has reference present in fragment XML
 * 
 *  android:onClick="myMethod"
 * 
 * @param v
 */
public void myMethod(View v) {
    DataItem item = new DataItem(String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()), String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()), String.valueOf(new Random().nextInt()), new Random().nextInt());
    DataProvider.addItem(item );
}
```

however your data-provider is storing data in memory, not in DB , i think you put it as example :)

try sample project , its simple and working 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2_EaCvs94pPeENtRlM4UURZYTQ